CDK deployment failed Resource timed out waiting for completion of AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachineAlias with deploymentPreference
CDK deployment updating the version of a Step Functions state machine with CANARY deployment preference fails after 2 hours because updating the Alias timed out.
2024-04-08 21:30:35 UTC-0700    Alias   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  -   -
2024-04-08 23:30:35 UTC-0700    Alias   UPDATE_FAILED       -   Resource timed out waiting for completion (RequestToken: GUID)

const stateMachineVersion = new CfnStateMachineVersion(scope, "Version", {
    stateMachineArn: stateMachine.stateMachineArn,
    stateMachineRevisionId: stateMachine.stateMachineRevisionId,
   });

const deployedAlias = new CfnStateMachineAlias(scope, "Alias", {
  name: "SomeAlias",
  deploymentPreference: {
    stateMachineVersionArn: stateMachineVersion.attrArn,
    type: "CANARY",
    interval: Duration.hours(2).toMinutes(),
    percentage: 10,
  },
});

I'm trying the deployment again now and I see the UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS event, and the state machine console shows the alias with 90% of traffic going to version:1 and 10% going to version:7.
